# Atributo como parametro de onClick

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo, en mi *html* unos elementos con atributos que necesito tener en el *js*.

Lo que intento hace es tratar de mandar esos atributos del elemento, como parametro y usarlos en el *js*.

Primero entente así:

```
<div id="main" nombre="Nombre Apellido" onclick="print(nombre)"></div>
```

---

Después así:

```
<div id="main" nombre="Nombre Apellido" onclick="print(this.nombre)"></div>
```

---

Tambien intenten abriendo las comillas y ponendile **+** para concatenar, y tampoco.
Actualmente lo tengo implementado como el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
function print(str){
  console.log(str.getAttribute('nombre'));
}
```

```css
#main{
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" nombre="Nombre Apellido" onclick="print(this)"></div>
```

---

Mi pregunta es: **Existe alguna otra forma de pasar atributos por parametro mejor q la manera q lo estoy haciendo?**

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que tratas de hacer. Podrías explicar un poco mas?

Comment: Bien, deja q edito

Comment: ahi se entiende mejor?

Comment: Te estás inventando un atributo **HTML** que no existe, "nombre". Prueba a sustituirlo por "name", debería de funcionarte. La única manera de tener atributos personalizados sería mediante el atributo **data-** de **HTML5**

Comment: de donde sale ese dato? creo que logro entender lo que quieres.

Comment: @PHPMyguel si, los nombre los atributos son inventados, tengo varios mas, pero ese es el ejemplo. Como seria mediante el atributo data?

Comment: @FranIslas que dato? el nombre? se va generando con lo q devuelve un _json_

Comment: **<div id="main" data-nombre="Nombre Apellido" onclick="print(this)"></div>** Me refiero a que no puedes usar un atributo "nombre", no existe en HTML y no te va a funcionar nada de lo que hagas con ese lemento.

Comment: @PHPMyguel por poder, puede añadir un atributo custom sin tener que inicializar por `data-` pero es preferible como comento en mi respuesta

Comment: Tienes razón @dteterevkov es la primera vez que lo veo, anodadado me hallo.

Comment: @PHPMyguel Comprendo, y si uso algun atributo como comentabas antes, como _name_, como lo puedo pasar directamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una forma mejor: el [dataset de HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

Supongamos que tenemos un elemento del que queremos guardar datos extra:

```
<ul>
<li>Pablo</li> <!-- Usuario 1, con rol ADMIN -->
<li>Pedro</li> <!-- Usuario 2, con rol USER -->
<li>Joaquín</li> <!-- Usuario 12, con rol ADVANCED_USER -->
</ul>
```

Así que queremos meter esos datos que están comentados en el HTML:

```js
let items= document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const element=event.currentTarget;
    const datos=element.dataset;
    console.log('Has clicado en el usuario',datos.id,'con permisos de', datos.role);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="1" data-role="ADMIN">Pablo</li> <!-- Usuario 1, con rol ADMIN -->
  <li data-id="2" data-role="USER">Pedro</li> <!-- Usuario 2, con rol USER -->
  <li data-id="12" data-role="ADVANCED_USER">Joaquín</li> <!-- Usuario 12, con rol ADVANCED_USER -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Bien, es como decía el link de la otra respuesta, mejorando el ejemplo.  Gracias

Answer (score 3):

La manera en la que haces funciona y está bien. A pesar de ello, tengo un par de consejos que pueden mejorar tu código:

1. Los atributos privados que añadas a los elementos deberían llamarse `data-`, en este caso, `data-nombre`. Por convenio y mejor legibilidad.
2. Separaría la lógica de JS de la estructura de HTML, es decir, no usaría `onclick` si no que lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```js
(() => {
  document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click", (el)=> {
    console.log(el.target.getAttribute("nombre"));
    
    });
})();
```

```css
#main{
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" nombre="Nombre Apellido"></div>
```

Comment: Comprendo, gracias por los consejos. La idea de traer el elemento con un **getElementById** también la pensé, pero quería saber si se podia enviar desde el _html_, ahora lo del data- solo sirve como estándar, y para mejorar la lectura? o tiene alguna funcionalidad?

Comment: @SArca es para evitar "hacks" como lo es crear un atributo que no "toca" en un elemento. Recomiendo la siguiente lectura: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos
Como allí dice, si quieres evitar usar la función `getAttribute` puedes acceder a todo aquello que esté definido como `data-` mediante la propiedad `dataset`.

Comment: Excelente, buen link ademas. Me anoto tus consejos. Gracias.