# Como hago para llamar a una funcion de JavaScript con atributos desde HTML

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, botón

mi problema creo que es muy simple, simplemente quiero meter mi variable ruta en la funcion que tengo en el onClick del boton con id eliminar. Para que así en el popup, que salga al pulsar el boton, pueda decidir si se quiere o no borrar el campo.

Este es mi código.

```
          <% var p = 1; %>
           <% for(var i=0; i < asignaturas.length; i++) { %>
             <%for (var j=0; j < user.asignaturas.length;j++){%>
               <%if(asignaturas[i]._id.toString()==user.asignaturas[j].toString() || user.rol == "Administrador"){%>              
             <tr>
               <td ><%= p++ %></td>
               <td>
               <a href="/software/<%= asignaturas[i]._id %>"><%= asignaturas[i].title%></a>
             </td>
               <td><%= asignaturas[i].description%></td>
               <td><%= asignaturas[i].info_instalacion%></td>

               <%if(user.rol == "Administrador" || user.rol == "Profesor"){%>
               <td>
                 <% var ruta = asignaturas[i]._id.toString %>
                 <a id="eliminar" onclick="pop_up()" class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</a>
                 <a href="/asignaturas/editar_asignaturas/<%= asignaturas[i]._id %>" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
               </td>
               <% } %>
               <% } %>
               <% } %>
             </tr>
           <% } %>
         </tbody>
       </table>
 
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <script>
   function pop_up(ruta) {
     var elemento = document.getElementById("eliminar");
     if (confirm("¿Estas seguro de que quieres eliminar?")) {
       elemento.setAttribute("href","/asignaturas/editar_asignaturas/"+ruta);
     } else {
       elemento.setAttribute("href","/asignaturas");
     }
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Atributo como parametro de onClick](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235742/atributo-como-parametro-de-onclick)

Comment: Creo que no puedo hacerlo así, debido a que en realidad no estoy pulsando en el item sino en un boton.

Comment: ¿Estás usando EJS como motor de plantillas?

Comment: Sip, es lo que estoy usando

Comment: y no le puedes  hacer así.  onclick="pop_up('<%= ruta %>')"

Comment: Lo he intentado, deja de reconocer el pop up y no lo hace. :(